# Ubuntu 16.04 with Libre Office Functionality

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I'm currently using Libre Office on Ubuntu 16.04 and I also have Libre Office install on my computer running Mac os X.  When I edit a document using the open document format, on Mac os X and then open the document on 16.04 the formatting inside the document is the same.  Is their a setting in Libre Office or Ubuntu 16.04 that needs to be adjusted?

Comment: "Is" the same or "is not" the same?

Comment: It is not the same...